# Why do we use the Hebrew name for Daniel, but Persian names for his companions?

Tags: old-testament, daniel

Reading the book of Daniel, an odd thing struck me: all four of the men were given Persian names and yet it's only Daniel that is now called by his Hebrew name.

Why is that we call his companions Shadrach, Meshach, and Abednego and not their original names of Hananiah, Mishael, and Azariah?

Comment: [Romanian Orthodox calendars](http://www.patriarhia.ro/images/Calendar_2020/12decembrie.jpg) list them by their Jewish names (December 17), most likely due to the influence of the [additions to Daniel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additions_to_Daniel) present in the [Greek Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint), specifically, the [prayer and song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prayer_of_Azariah_and_Song_of_the_Three_Holy_Children) attributed to them by their Jewish names.

Comment: [Greek](http://www.goarch.org/chapel/saints?contentid=341) and [Russian](http://www.oca.org/saints/lives/2020/12/17/103560) calendars seem to employ the same usage as well.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is rather general, I'm going to offer a suggestion - a pretty plausible one, but a suggestion. It's probably because they are central to one famous story in the book of Daniel - the fiery furnace - and in that story (which is written in Aramaic) they are given their "Persian" names. After that story, they don't appear in the book at all. In other words, we think "Shadrach, Meshach, and Abednego" immediately in connection to the story of the fiery furnace, and in that story, they have those Persian names.

Daniel, on the other hand, is mentioned  65 times in the book with his Hebrew name, and ten times as Belteshazzar.